# Removing elements containing NaN in R list

Tags: r

I have written a function that returns such a list:

```
$F1
[1] NaN

$F2
[1] NaN

$F3
[1] NaN

$F4
[1] NaN

$F5
[1] NaN

$F1_a
[1] NaN

$F2_a
        a         b         c         d         e 
 0.602060 -0.090309 -0.090309 -0.090309 -0.090309 

$F3_a
[1] NaN

$F4_a
           a            b            c            d            e 
 6.000000000  0.001259629  3.830705151 23.992442227  0.084647425 

$F5_a
[1] NaN

$F1_b
[1] NaN

$F2_b
      a       b       c       d       e 
1.20412 0.00000 0.60206 1.20412 0.00000 

$F3_b
[1] NaN

$F4_b
 a  b  c  d  e 
28  0  6  6  0 

$F5_b
[1] NaN
```

Is it possible to keep only the elements containing no `NaN`'s?
I have tried looping through it and saving only those where each element is `FALSE` to `is.nan`, but I found no way to keep the names. Have you got any suggestions?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `Filter`.  Based on the data, `NaN`s are only found in elements with `length` of 1.

```
Filter(function(x) !(is.nan(x) && length(x) == 1), lst1)
```

If we want to remove elements having `any` 'NaN' i.e. elements such as `c(5, NaN)` will be removed as well

```
Filter(function(x) !any(is.nan(x)), lst1)
```

#### data

```
lst1 <- list(F1 = NaN, F2 = NaN, F3 = NaN, F4 = NaN, F1_a = NaN, F2_a = c(a = 0.602, 
b = -0.0903, c = -903))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sapply` to keep only those list elements that have only non-NA value in them.

```
lst[sapply(lst, function(x) all(!is.na(x)))]
```

`purrr` also has `keep` and `discard` functions for this :

```
purrr::keep(lst, ~all(!is.na(.x)))
purrr::discard(lst, ~any(is.na(.x)))
```